# Cannot implicitly convert type Dictionary<String,int> to int

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to develop an Xna project and  make a collision detection mechanism.I have a Dictionary object like :

```
Dictionary<string, int> boneIndices = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

and I want to get indixes from this dictionary like at the above line :

```
 int boneIndex = this.animator.skinningData.BoneIndices;
```

but I take an error which is at the topic.

How can ı solve this error?

Comment: You need to get the value of an entry of your dictionay, e.g. using the indexer: `boneIndices["test"]`

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to provide a key to find a value, like following:

```
int boneIndex = this.animator.skinningData.BoneIndices["someKey"];
```

What the error is saying is that you are assigning the whole dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, int>` to a variable of type `int`. Apart from using indexer as I showed you, there are some other ways to get a value from a dictionary. You can find them on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure the key exists within the dictionary, you can take a safer approach using `TryGetValue`:

```
string key = "key";
int indice = 0;

if (!animator.skinningData.BoneIndices.TryGetValue(key, out indice)
{
     // If you get here, the key doesn't exist
}
```

Using an indexer directly may throw a `KeyNotFoundException` if the key isn't present in the dictionary.